# How to take advantage of kernel.terminate inside an event listener

Tags: symfony

In my bundle, I want to take advantage of the `kernel.terminate` event to flush some statistics about webservice api call. Yet, I didn't find any resources to do it in the best way.

On a listener `GuzzleExceptionListener` (his role is to intercept every fail webservice call) in which i've injected the `EntityManger` service. :

```
if ($exception instanceof BadResponseException) {
    $entityManager = $this->entityManager;

    $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher;
    $dispatcher->addListener('kernel.terminate', function (Event $event) use ($entityManager) {
        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository("somerepository");
        // do some treatment for stats
        $entityManager->persist($apicall);
        $entityManager->flush();
    });
}
```

The declaration of the `GuzzleExceptionListener` :

```
<service id="my_service" class="%my_class%">
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.exception" method="onKernelException" />
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
</service>
```

Anyhow, this closure is not called when the event `kernel.terminate` is fired. Why ? Is it because it's inside a listener itself ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should inject symfony's configured event dispatcher service (`@event_dispatcher`) instead of creating a new one inside the listener.

If you only create it and add an event-listener symfony still has no reference to this newly created `EventDispatcher` object and therefore won't use it.

```
<service id="my_service" class="%my_class%">
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.exception" method="onKernelException" />
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
    <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher" />
 </service>
```