# Symfony2 event subscriber does not call listeners

Tags: symfony, event-handling

I am trying to set up a simple event subscription based on the example given here - http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html.

Here's my event store:

```
namespace CookBook\InheritanceBundle\Event;

final class EventStore
{
    const EVENT_SAMPLE = 'event.sample';
}
```

Here's my event subscriber:

```
namespace CookBook\InheritanceBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class Subscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        var_dump('here');
        return array(
                'event.sample' => array(
                        array('sampleMethod1', 10),
                        array('sampleMethod2', 5)
                ));
    }

    public function sampleMethod1(Event $event)
    {
        var_dump('Method 1');
    }

    public function sampleMethod2(Event $event)
    {
        var_dump('Method 2');
    }
}
```

Here's the config in services.yml:

```
kernel.subscriber.subscriber:
    class: CookBook\InheritanceBundle\Event\Subscriber
    tags:
        - {name:kernel.event_subscriber}
```

And here's how I raise the event:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use CookBook\InheritanceBundle\Event\EventStore;
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$dispatcher->dispatch(EventStore::EVENT_SAMPLE);
```

Expected output:

```
string 'here' (length=4)
string 'Method 1' (length=8)
string 'Method 2' (length=8)
```

Actual output:

```
string 'here' (length=4)
```

For some reason, the listener methods don't get called. Anyone knows what's wrong with this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try to inject a configured `EventDispatcher` (`@event_dispatcher`) instead of instanciating a new one (`new EventDispatcher`)

If you only create it and add an event-listener Symfony still has no reference to this newly created `EventDispatcher` object and won't use it.

If you are inside a controller who extends ContainerAware :

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use CookBook\InheritanceBundle\Event\EventStore;

...

$dispatcher = $this->getContainer()->get('event_dispatcher');
$dispatcher->dispatch(EventStore::EVENT_SAMPLE);
```

I've adapted my answer thanks to [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671825/how-to-take-advantage-of-kernel-terminate-inside-an-event-listener) even though the context of both questions are different, the answer still applies.

Comment: Cheers, Tristan. I gotta revisit my understanding of dependency injection in symfony.

Comment: I see you more or less just copy-pasted my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671825/how-to-take-advantage-of-kernel-terminate-inside-an-event-listener) to your own question  without referencing it here - please give some credit to the original answerer next time :)

Comment: Yeah totally I didn't linked because the context was different, for me  I was already inside a listener, so i was afraid it would confuse things up. But your answer totally applies for this question.

Answer (score 8):

What @Tristan said.  The tags portion in your services file is part of the Symfony Bundle and is only processed if you pull the dispatcher out of the container.

Your example will work as expected if you do this:

```
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$dispatcher->addSubscriber(new Subscriber());
$dispatcher->dispatch(EventStore::EVENT_SAMPLE);
```

Comment: Cheers, Cerad. I was looking for injection from config file specifically, which is what Tristan has presented.

Comment: I fully understand.  @Tristan deserves the credit.  This was more to document why it works from the container as opposed to your posted code.